# Running a webserver inside a ubuntu image in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ubuntu, webserver

I'm planning to run my existing rails application from a ubuntu image in docker where the host machine is Windows 10.

I did port binding with `docker run -p 6000:3000 -td myimage`.Then I login into the container using this command `docker exec -it mycontainer bash`. Then I've used `git` to get my app and installed all the dependency and gems and the server starts normally in port `3000` of the container ([See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Lwk.png))

When I open `localhost:6000` on my host Windows machine, I found no response. I tried searching a lot but no results. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you supposed to see anything when you open up a browser and go to localhost:6000?

Comment: Yes a html page. I also created a new app to see if my code from git is bugged. It seems same problem. My host pc's localhost:6000 don't get any response.

Comment: What is the output of this command? `lsof -i:6000`

Comment: Anything you do in that `docker exec` shell will be lost as soon as the container exits.  This is a debugging command that you shouldn't need routinely.  Instead, your Dockerfile should describe how to build a complete image containing your application, `docker build` will build it, and you can `docker run` a new container from the image without typing manual shell commands.  `docker rm` the container when the program exits is normal and inexpensive; don't worry about preserving the container as a special thing.

Comment: You can go inside the container and use curl to see what is returned too

Comment: @DavidMaze I used "docker exec -it mycontainer bash" to open up bash shell in cmd and installed necessary stuffs inside that container. If I close and restart the container, every thing was still there.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan I used windows equivalent command and couldn't found that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was actually problem from rails I think. Using "rails s -b 0.0.0.0 " to start up the server instead of "rails s" solved the problem, which binds directly localhost. Thank you everyone for your help!